# filemaker database relationships

Tags: database, database-design, filemaker

I'm very new to FileMaker currently working on a Mac. I've been assigned a new simple system to work towards completing and I have bumped into some issues with database relationships. I've got experience with PHP/MySQL databases connections etc. but FileMaker seems to require a somewhat different mindset and approach.

I'll try to explain this as simply as I can.

[Here's the table relationships in my database](https://puu.sh/rqwgL/24b7a4861b.png)

[image]

What I'm trying to do is a list of "to-do" notes, an interactive menu where the user can add things that needs to be done. I've done this with a portal on a layout based on the table "site". The portal is based on the table "todo_notes", which is connected to site through the "site_id".

[Here's what it looks like in browse mode](https://puu.sh/rqwl9/1f22d07bcc.png)

[image]

What I'm having problems with is adding a relationship between the todo_notes and contacts. The contacts are two separate tables called "county_contacts" and "property_owner_contacts". What I want to accomplish is the possibility for the user to, from a dropdown-list, add a single contact from these two tables. Preferably I'd like to sort of merge these two tables into the same dropdown-list.

Let me know if you need any other information or a better explanation of my issue. Any help is very welcome!

Comment: "*The contacts are two separate tables*" I believe that is a mistake - regardless of which relational database you're using. -- P.S. Please make your questions self-contained.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll try keeping the contacts in one table and see if I can resolve the issue somehow from there. Also, what do you mean by keeping the question self-contained?

Comment: "*what do you mean by keeping the question self-contained?*" See above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single contacts table with foreign keys for both county and property owner tables, that would let you have a single list for all contacts. From there you could also build a value list based on a relationship, for example to filter only contacts that belong to either county or property owners.

If you then need to further normalize the tables, fields that pertain to either relationship exclusively could be moved to another table from there, as a one to one relationship, if that is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

**The Short Answer**
You need to create a Contacts table.  Filemaker has no way of dynamically generating value lists. Instead, you can base a value list on any field, therefore, the only way of generating a list of the contact names would be if they were all in the same table.

**The Long Answer**
Because Filemaker only allows us to use ONE field for a value list, we must create a new table for the contact.  I would recommend that you replace the two contact tables with a single contact table,(seeing as the fields look the same between the two tables) and then add a toggle on the contact for Owner or County.  However, you could also create a single contact table for all of the fields that overlap that has foreign keys to the owner and county tables.

You would then use the fullname field from the contact and be good to go.

That is, assuming that you did not want to filter the contacts at all or only show contacts associated with this site.

To start with, I highly recommend using the Anchor-buoy method for organizing the relationship graph. Here's an explanation of the anchor-buoy method: http://sixfriedrice.com/wp/six-fried-rice-methodology-part-2-anchor-buoy-and-data-structures/ . It's just a convention, but will help you with the idea of context in FileMaker. It's widely accepted among the FileMaker community as the "right" way to organize a relationship graph.  I will continue my explanation using this method.

Each Table Occurrence (the boxes in the graphs, or TO) represents a unique context from which you can view and edit information.  In the anchor buoy method, each Table only has one "anchor" TO.  I would recommend only using anchor TO's for the context of your layouts. Then, your portal, and any other corresponding information, will be on your buoy TO's. [Here is what your new portal relationship would look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w31iu.png)  You would select fields from your buoy TO's to use in the portal.

The easiest way to filter your value list by only contacts associated with this site would be to create a foreign key from the contact table to the site, and then add a TO to the graph, for the contact table. You would then click "Include only related values starting from" radio button, and specify your new TO.